# signed char doesn't overflow when result of arithmetic operation is assigned. But when a numeric value is assigned, it overflows. Please explain

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Consider following C code

```
int main() {
    signed char result = 129;
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming char is 8 bit, 129 causes overflow, hence result of printf will be -127. I'm clear with this part.

But when i try the following:

```
int main() {
    signed char a=100,b=3;
    signed char c= 4;
    signed char result = a*b/c;
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Then as per the convention, as `a` and `b` are `signed char`, `a*b` will be a `signed char`. Hence, `300` will overflow, so, only LSB(least significant 8 bits should be considered). This will make it `44` and when divided by `4`, it should print `11` and not `75`. I'm confused here.

Comment: `a*b/c;` is performed after all the operands are promoted to `int`, so no overflow is happening. `75` is the correct result.

Comment: See [Implicit Conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) under Integer Conversions: [if the target type cannot hold the value] and if the target type is signed, the behavior is implementation-defined (which may include raising a signal). This applies to the first example.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so, firstly the result of a*b is determined. But this temporary result is stored as int, instead of signed char? automatic promotion is happening or is it called something else?

Comment: You say: "`a*b` will be a `signed char`". That's wrong. It will be an `int`.

Comment: @AdrianMole why will it be an int, when the variable type is an `signed char`?shouldn't the intermediate results be of the same data type as that of operands?

Comment: It's the rules of C. There's surely a duplicate around somewhere, about arithmetic operators, operands and integer promotions ...

Comment: More specifically, your values undergoes [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), which leads to *integer promotion*.

Comment: OK - Found a FAQ and will close this as a duplicate. If anyone finds better targets, ping me and I'll add them to the close banner.

Comment: @JohnFilleau gotcha! Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i got it.Thanks!